Tomcat failing, partially shutting down, after a delay
We have a number of Tomcat instances, all of which get a bit upset after running for exactly 655,000 seconds.
What we see is that  tomcat.pid disappears, and Catalina.out gets closed, but apart from that the service still runs apparently normally, and responds to requests.
The lack of tomcat.pid confuses the rest of the system, which reports Tomcat as being down.
I can't find any reference to 655000 anywhere.
Nor can I find any error messages.
Anyone got any ideas what might be going on?
This is Tomcat 9.0.80   on Solaris
